# Unable to insert second record in realm database

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am using realm as my backend. I am storing two strings.The problem is when I insert the records first time it works perfectly but when I insert the records again it shows an error.

My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tablee:UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var msgTxt:UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var img:UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var vieww:UIView!


let msg = Msg()
let realm = try! Realm()
lazy var msgs: Results<Msg> = { self.realm.objects(Msg.self) }()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
}
@IBAction func msgSend(_ sendeR:UIButton) {
    if img.image != nil {
        let image : UIImage = self.img.image!
        let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData
        let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
        print(strBase64)
        let pureStr = String(strBase64)
        msg.imgurl = pureStr!
    } else {
        msg.imgurl = "none"
    }
    msg.content = msgTxt.text
    let realm = try! Realm()
    do {
        try realm.write() {
            realm.add(msg)
        }
    } catch {

    }
    self.tablee.reloadData()
    self.msgTxt.text = ""
}
}
```

Error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756349/realmswift-rlmexception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs because you only have one single `Msg` object created. Here:

```
let msg = Msg()
```

Since this is placed outside of a class, it will only create one instance of `Msg` every time the enclosing class is instantiated.

When you first press the button, everything is good. `msg` is saved into the database. When you press the button a second time, you are modifying the same `msg` object, which is already in the database! To modify something that's already saved, you need to put the code in a `write` block. But you didn't, so the exception occurs.

What I think you intended to do was to create a new `Msg` object every time the button is pressed. To do this, you need to declare `msg` as a local variable,  or reassign `msg` in the IBAction.

```
@IBAction func msgSend(_ sendeR:UIButton) {
    msg = Msg() // this line creates a new Msg object so as not to modify the same one over and over.
    if img.image != nil {
        let image : UIImage = self.img.image!
        let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData
        let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
        print(strBase64)
        let pureStr = String(strBase64)
        msg.imgurl = pureStr!
```